Use value in table as part of Laravel RawQuery searching for results within X radius of coordinates
I currently have a fixed radius of 50km, which is an ENV constant, for finding all users within X radius of a particular set of coordinates. What I would like to achieve is allowing users to set their own radius, up to a maximum of 50km and use this value in the search.
User::selectRaw('*, (6371 * acos (cos ( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( addressLat ) ) * cos( radians( addressLong ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin ( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( addressLat ) ))) AS distance')->orderBy('distance')->having('distance', '<', $radius)->whereNotNull('phone_number')->where('should_receive_quotes', '!=', '0')->get();
$radius = env('RADIUS',50); is the variable currently.
Is it possible to be able to use the value within the users table radius to check whether that user is within the radius of the given coordinates and their custom radius? If there is no value set in the users radius column then it defaults to 50km.
I'm hoping to be able to use the value in the users table as part of the RawQuery
Users table:



id
lat
lng
radius




1
51.500836
-1.159058
80


2
51.164490
-0.466919
NULL


3
52.39103
-2.91020
NULL



Quotes table:



id
lat
lng




1
51.267715
-0.214233



Based on the above data, for quote ID 1 I would expect it to return users 1 & 2. User 2 would be within the default 50km of quote ID 1, User 1 would be within 80km of quote ID 1, based on the custom radius defined in the Users table radius column. User 3 would not be returned because it has a NULL radius column and it is outside of the default 50km radius.

Use COALESCE to apply dynamic radius to each user
->having('distance', '<', DB::raw('COALESCE(radius, ' . $radius . ')'))

